# Ansible docker_login module error : Error while fetching server API version

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-pull

I am trying to login to private docker container registry using Ansible module (docker_login) on Mac. It works fine on Ubuntu latest, however Mac fails with below error. I have tried installing pip module for docker, docker-py and requests. none of these helps.

```
"changed": false, "msg": "Error connecting: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))"
```

Code Block:

```
- name: Login to Docker Registry
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:  

    - name: Install docker
      pip:
        name: docker
        
    - name: Install docker
      pip:
        name: requests

    - name: login
      docker_login:
        registry: "registryhidden"
        username: "user"
        password: "password"

    - name: Pull image
      docker_image:
        name: registryhidden/hellow-world:2.2.0
        source: pull
```

Login succeed and pull the image

Docker Info

```html
Docker info
Client:
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.0)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.15.1)
  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc., v0.0.5)
  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc., v0.2.17)
  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc., 0.6.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.23.0)

Server:
 Containers: 38
  Running: 34
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 4
 Images: 33
 Server Version: 20.10.22
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 9ba4b250366a5ddde94bb7c9d1def331423aa323
 runc version: v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.49-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: aarch64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.668GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: EGCA:3ZEX:YMYL:IUTN:FGUA:FOIQ:JIVQ:4B27:TMYK:3YDO:DSH2:WCN5
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128
 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

➜  Downloads
```

Comment: Hi dasharath Mangali welcome to SO. It's `FileNotFound` because by default docker clients assume the fifo is in `/var/run/docker.sock` but on Mac `docker` communicates with the dockerd over TCP (it's in the `$DOCKER_HOST` env var); what does running `docker info` on your Mac tell you?

Comment: @mdaniel thanks for your response,  I have updated my post with docker info, let me know if you need any other information from my side.

Comment: I accept responsibility for not checking that `docker info` would include its `$DOCKER_HOST` value, sorry about that. What is in the `$DOCKER_HOST` value on your Mac? Failing that, you'll want to look in `~/.docker/contexts` to see what's in `desktop-linux`. The objective is that somewhere in all that is a `tcp://` value that points to your actual `dockerd` endpoint, and that's what you'll have to provide to `docker_login:` (and maybe other tasks) so python can reach `dockerd` since it cannot use `/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @mdaniel thank you so much again I am seeing below response, not sure what i have do here 

➜  Desktop ~/.docker/contexts
➜  contexts ls
meta
➜  contexts echo $DOCKER_HOST 

➜  contexts

Comment: @mdaniel

➜  `contexts cat meta/fe9c6bd7a66301f49ca9b6a70b217107cd1284598bfc254700c989b916da791e/meta.json                                                                                 
{"Name":"desktop-linux","Metadata":{},"Endpoints":{"docker":{"Host":"unix:///Users/xxxxxxxx/.docker/run/docker.sock","SkipTLSVerify":false}}}% `

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance, I would never have guessed that path; anyway, you'll want to try adding [`docker_host: unix:///Users/xxxxxxxx/.docker/run/docker.sock`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/7/collections/community/docker/docker_login_module.html#parameter-docker_host) assuming that path actually exists. If that does in fact work, you can try adding `environment: { DOCKER_HOST: unix:///Users/xxxxxxxx/.docker/run/docker.sock }` to your playbook, such that all tasks inherit it. Let us know how that works out for you!

Comment: @mdaniel I have added the docker host to the docker login but still i have same error 

  docker_login:
    docker_host: "unix:///Users/xxxxx/.docker/run/docker.sock"

Comment: What happens if you run that at increased verbosity (`-vvvv`)? And it's the same `FileNotFoundError`?